# Does it really take a 50 reputation to make a proposal on area51?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51

I have a great (I think) proposal for area 51 but couldn't figure out how to propose it, did some research and found out you need a rep of 50? Am I right? How does that make sense?

and about the getting 50 from confirming your email, i connected my area 51 account to an already existing stackoverflow gmail acount so it didnt even send me a confirmation email at all

k, so now i got the 50 rep, and i go to start a discussion, and it says "You must have at least 5 reputation on Area 51" and ONLY ON THAT PAGE does it drop my rep back down to 1

Comment: Interesting point. There is nothing in the Area 51 FaQ the mentions rep needed.

Comment: @tombull89 Yes I think it does.

Comment: @tombull89: Interesting, but completely incorrect. Are we reading the same FAQ here? http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq To quote that page directly, "You'll earn your first 50 reputation from confirming your email address. This will allow you to create proposals and example questions"; this is mentioned also in the table of required rep on the same page. You may want to read the whole thing before you claim that something *isn't* there.

Comment: I mean that the OPs question was an interestion point, not my comment. There is nothing _where I would expect it_. The second section you get to says "how to create a new site" although it mentions nothing about rep until you read further on.

Comment: @tombull89: `<nitpick>`"I skimmed the first screen and did not see it" != "it is not there at all"`</nitpick>`

Comment: Piskvor - fair comment.

Comment: @bzupnick: You should file your 1-rep drop-down problem as a new [bug]-question. It might not be related.

Comment: Frankly one of the biggest problems with Area 51 **is** the low reputation requirements for creating proposals.   4 out of 5 new proposals are either ill-defined, covered by an existing site or proposal, or just plain crazy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

YA RLY. Did you check the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)? It says there:

> Amass enough reputation points and Area 51 grant you additional privileges:
>   [...]
>   50    Create proposals

Note that it also says

> You'll earn your first 50 reputation from confirming your email address. This will allow you to create proposals and example questions.

How does that *not* make sense?

( See also the page on this specific privilege: http://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-proposals )

How to send the verification: on your profile page, there should be a link saying "send e-mail verification to [your e-mail]" - see screenshot:

[image: link to send mail verification]

After clicking, I have immediately received an e-mail with a link; clicking it gave me this "address verified" banner:

[image: +50 rep for verification]

Comment: but i connected it to a stackoverflow gmail acount so it didnt even send me a confirmation at all!

Comment: @bzupnick: A-ha! That changes the situation considerably. Not sure what to do about *that*, though :(

Comment: a-ha!! is it like a bug or something? or something that just wasnt considered? it seems a little weird though....

Comment: @bzupnick: I tried it - there's a link to verification in your profile. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need a reputation score of at least 50. And if you read the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) it states:

> You'll earn your first **50 reputation** from confirming your email address. This will allow you to create proposals and example questions.

So, sign up and confirm your email address and you'll be given the 50 reputation you need.

For more info on how to earn reputation on Area 51, check out the [Reputation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) section of the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do need 50 rep on it.

You can get 50 by confirming your email in your profile. I got mine by having more than 200 rep on a SE site, which means I get a +100 bonus on Area 51.